# Ruby docs rindex example

Tags: ruby, fixnum

This example is from the ruby docs.

```
"hello".rindex(/[aeiou]/, -2)   #=> 1
```

Why does this output 1 instead of 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the second parameter. From the doc

> If the second parameter is present, it specifies the position in the
>   string to end the search—characters beyond this point will not be
>   considered.

So

```
"hello".rindex(/[aeiou]/)
 => 4
```

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)